# Get the username of a windows user

Tags: php

I would like to use php to look for a specific downloaded file in the downloads. If that file is found it should then be unlinked using php function. I can't seem to find the username. the getenv() function just gets the name of the computer.

My path is as follows C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\example.delete

Regardless of who is logged in, i Would like to do the same for each user. This is what I have:  'C:\users\'.getenv('username').'\Downloads\eaxmple.delete';
This gets the pc name instead of the logged in user.
Suggestions

Comment: You can't do this using PHP for PHP is run by the server and has no access to files on the client computer.

Comment: you'll only be able to do something like this on the server.  I hope you don't mean getting this from your user

Comment: What says he is not doing this as a script to run on the server (which is a windows computer)? PHP do not neseserly have to be for a webpage.

Comment: yes, its a windows computer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
echo $_ENV["USER"];
?>
```